# Using same ng-repeat on one page - best practice?

Tags: angularjs

In need the data from a ng-repeat on two places within the view. The code below works, but I am not sure if this is the way to do it. (I am new to Angular).

If a user clicks on a outlet-option the outlet-products get displayed. First I loaded the products below the outlet-option and used jQuery to move to the productsWrapper if a user clicks on an option. But then I needed to compile it again which made it a bit messy in my opinion.

There can be only one "#productsWrapper" and one ".outlet", so I came up with using the ng-repeat twice. But is this the way to go?

```
<div id="productsWrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index" class="products" style="display: none;" id="prod-{{element.wonelement_id}}">
        <outlet-product ng-repeat   = "option in element.options"
                        class       = "product"
                        option-data = "option"
                        element-data= "element"
                        chosen-data = "chosen">
        </outlet-product>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outlet">
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index">
        <outlet-option
                element-data = "element"
                option-data  = "element.option"
                chosen-data  = "chosen"
                app-settings = "app">
        </outlet-option>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you proposed looks fine in a typical AngularJS way.

If you were applying filters to the ng-repeat clause, then I would have suggested applying that filter ahead of time in the controller so that it would only be run the one time.  But since you are using no filters at all on the data, I think it is fine as you have it.

Comment: @shieldstroy Because somebody didn't like the question, downvoted it, and simply kept going down the page and downvoted my answer because, hey, why not, right?